# Can't find the .class file when running a junit test

Tags: java, junit

Here is the directory structure of [a Java program](http://booksite.elsevier.com/9780123705914/exercises/12~Chapter_16.zip), created for NetBean IDE:

```
$ ls
build.xml  manifest.mf  nbproject  src  test
```

The `package` statement in  `src/steal/MMThread.java` is

```
package steal;
```

I compile the .java file by

```
$ javac src/steal/MMThread.java -d bin/steal/
$ ls bin/steal/
MMThread.class  MMThread$Worker.class
```

I then compiled and ran the Java Junit test program. Compilation is fine, but running test isn't. What shall I do then? Thanks

```
$ javac -cp bin/:/home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar test/steal/MMThreadTest.java 

$ ls test/steal/
 MMThreadTest.class  MMThreadTest.java

$ java -cp bin/:/home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  steal.MMThreadTest
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: steal.MMThreadTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:996)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:173)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:670)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:486)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:553)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:486)
    ... 15 more
```

---

Update

```
$ java -cp test/:bin/:/home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  steal.MMThreadTest
JUnit version 4.11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:996)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:173)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:670)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:486)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:553)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:486)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: what if you change to `-cp test:bin:...  steal.MMThreadTest` in the second call?

Comment: Thanks. no not found error any more. Could you explain a little? Still other errors, see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class path setting is incorrect. It needs to have:

- junit
- hamcrest (dependency of junit)
- the path to the folder that has your `.class` files

The jar of hamcrest should be in the same directory where you have junit.
Look in `/home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins`.
You could use the `find` command to find it:

```
find /home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins -name '*hamcrest*.jar'
```

If your machine doesn't have hamcrest,
you can download from here:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar

Once you have that, you can put the pieces together:

```
junit=/home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar
hamcrest=/home/t/program_files/programming/eclipse/plugins/idontknowwhere/hamcrest.jar
java -cp "$junit:$hamcrest:test/steal" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MMThreadTest
```

Comment: Thanks. My machine doesn't have hamcrest.jar any where

Comment: @Ben then you can download it from here: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar

Comment: Thanks. Is there some convention for where I store downloaded .jar files on my Ubuntu?

Comment: @Ben The way you're using them, no. The convention is to use Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies of your Java projects, and these tools will keep them organized in their dedicated storage (actually Gradle typically reuses Maven's, under `~/.m2`)

Comment: Thanks. How do Java programmers use Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies? In command line?

Comment: @Ben Java programmers typically use IDE's like Eclipse and IntelliJ, which have plugins for Maven and Gradle to manage dependencies. But you don't need an IDE to use Maven or Gradle, they both work as command line applications as well. For example, to compile a project you could do `mvn compile`, and run all tests in a project with `mvn test`.

Comment: Thanks. The example given in http://benjamintan.io/blog/2014/10/14/running-junit-test-from-the-command-line/ doesn't specify hamcrest during both running and compiling the unit test file, while I didn't specify hamcrest during compiling but during running. Why is the difference?

Comment: @Ben the example uses a wildcard `*` in the classpath. You don't see what exactly gets included. That article would be much better if it had explicitly stated the files involved. With the wildcard, we just cannot know what is required for it to work. But it must be the same: junit + hamcrest.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Another question: is it correct that I don't need to specify hamcrest when compiling the junit test, but need to when running it? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46657077

Comment: @Ben responded ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not hamcrest.

This code uses Junit 3.8.2 and you are providing Junit 4 in the classpath.
So remove 4 and add Junit 3.8.2

Comment: Thanks. How can I install it?

Comment: Have a look at the project properties in NetBeans. There you should see where the Hamcrest jar comes from.

Comment: something is confusing me: you say that you are using NetBans but taking Junit jar from your Eclipse installation? And why are you running the junit tests outside NetBeans?

Comment: I am not the author of the program, and I don't use NetBeans

Comment: this is an example out of a book. and it's NetBeans configuration. So why don't you use NetBeans?

Comment: bc I don't know how to use NB

Comment: Do you know any other IDE?

Comment: No, although I have installed eclipse

Comment: Then you should start to get familiar with Eclipse and then when you know how to use it import the project from the book.

Comment: I want to learn about the commands first, before using an IDE.

Comment: So then you should read a java introduction tutorial but nobody is programming Java without IDE. Have a look at this. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html