# Do I need to specify indirectly imported package when compiling and running?

Tags: java

If a .java file imports  a package `A` which in turn imports another package `B`,

- when I compile the .java file to get its .class file using `javac` in command line, do I need to specify after `-cp` the path to `B.class` as well as the path to `A.class`?
- when I run the .class file using `java` in command line, do I need to specify after `-cp` the path to `B.class` as well as the path to `A.class`?

[From an example of junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653433), compiling the test doesn't require specifying  hamcrest to `javac -cp`, while running the test does. Is the answer to the first question about compiling "no", and the answer to the second question about running "yes"?

Thanks.

Comment: Well yes, but an import is just a key stroke saving tool for developers. After compilation, all classes are fully qualified.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific about which question(s) you said "yes" to, what you mean by "an import is just a key stroke saving tool for developers", and by "After compilation, all classes are fully qualified"?

Comment: *do I need to specify after -cp the path to B.class as well as the path to A.class?* Yes. *do I need to specify after -cp the path to B.class as well as the path to A.class?* Yes. And I meant `import java.util.Scanner;` just adds `java.util.Scanner` to the local name space - allowing you to type `Scanner` - but the compiler will still replace **all** short names with their full form.

Comment: Thanks. Although you omitted it in your commend, do you know that my first question is for compiling by `javac` and my second question is for running by `java`?

Comment: Don't just take my word for it. Go try it. Should take you less than the 34 minutes this has taken.

Comment: If you read my post, I have tried in the other link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - when I compile the .java file to get its .class file using `javac` in command line, do I need to specify after `-cp` the path to `B.class` as well as the path to `A.class`?

Yes. When you compile a `.java` file, the compiler needs to find all the symbols (classes) imported by that file. So if your `.java` file imports class A, the class loader needs to load it. If class A imports class B, then the class loader needs to load that too. This happens recursively.

And how does the class loader know where to find the classes?
It searches for classes in the classpath.
If it cannot find something on the classpath,
it will not be able to proceed and raise an error.

> - when I run the .class file using `java` in command line, do I need to specify after `-cp` the path to `B.class` as well as the path to `A.class`?

Yes, for exactly the same reason as in the previous point.

> [From an example of junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653433/641955), compiling the test doesn't require specifying  hamcrest to `javac -cp`, while running the test does.

When you run the tests,
you're not executing your test class,
you're executing the `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` class.
So the dependencies that you have to provide are not only the dependencies of your test class,
but also the dependencies of `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`,
in this example hamcrest.

Comment: Thanks. In the junit test, compiling the test doesn't require specifying hamcrest to `javac -cp` though. Why is that?

Comment: @Ben When you compile the tests, only what you import is required (and its recursive dependencies). For example `org.junit.Test`, `org.junit.Assert`, and so, and apparently they don't use hamcrest.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you might want to change your answer to my first question.

Comment: @Ben I don't see it, what do you mean?

Comment: The first question of mine asks when I compile a .java file which imports package A, where by the way package A in turn imports package B, shall I specify the paths of both `A.class` and `B.class` to `-cp` of `javac`? Your answer is yes.

Comment: @Ben Yes, my answer is still yes to that question. You must specify the paths of everything your class imports and everything they import. And then when you run `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`, you again specify the paths of everything your class imports, and in addition, everything that `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` imports. So you specify more than when you were compile, because `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` was not present when you compiled, but it's present when you run tests.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. I heard that `junit.jar` depends on `hamcrest.jar`. If the .java file imports junit, do I need to import hamcrest?

Comment: @Ben in `import` statements, what do you import? Not jars. You import classes. Some classes in `junit.jar` import classes from `hamcrest.jar`, others don't. For example `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` (or one of its imports) imports from `hamcrest.jar`, but `org.junit.Test` and `org.junit.Assert` don't.